# Add input text when option selected

Tags: jquery, select, input

How can I add an an `<input type="text">` when a specific option between `<select></select>` tags is selected, then, if another option is selected, delete that text field  using jQuery?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I did not, I don't know where to start. I have no idea. I don't want somebody to do all my work, I need an idea about it.

Comment: Do you want to add/delete from the dom or hiding is good enough ?

Comment: I want to add/delete the form, because I will check if it exists with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of `change` event. Then you could compare the value for which you want to create the input and add it to the `body` or to any other element.

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/MKPdb/

Having a list like this, with the id `mylist`, for example:

```
<select id="mylist">
 ...
</select>
```

You could use this:

```
$('#mylist').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '1'){
        $('body').append('<input id="myInput" type="text" />');
    }else{
        $('#myInput').remove();
    }
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/MKPdb/

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of a `<select>`, use the `.val()` method. To add/remove an element, there are several options. I will give you one of them example:

```
$('<input type="text" />').appendTo('body'); // Will append this element to <body>
$('input').remove(); // Removes this item from the document
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a  then add it where you want and set it to display none and then get it from JQuery

```
<select id="mylist">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="1" >aaaa</option>
     <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
</select>
<input id="id" type="text" style="display:none;" />
```

then into your JS

```
$('#mylist').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '1'){
        $('#id').show();
    }else{
        $('#id').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is about adding/removing not showing/hiding form element. The difference does matter as even the hidden form element will be submitted when the form is submitted, but the element that's removed will not.