# Link Select Input to Another Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my inputs to link to the other input using jQuery, while the all 3 inputs stays at their places and not vanish.

```
Input 1 ->   Input 2 ->      Input 3 ->     
Selected    Choose option   Choose option
```

Finally, when the user click on all selection, the "**Go button**" will appear next, and will have a unique hyperlink inside.

like that:

```
Input 1 ->   Input 2 ->      Input 3 ->     Go Button (with unique hyperlink to each selection)
Selected    Choose option   Choose option
```

I have  seen this [Add input text when option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420788/add-input-text-when-option-selected), but this is don't what I need, but the opposite.

Something like that http://jsfiddle.net/Mm2mu/2/ but without the radio boxes.

See here the image example http://oi62.tinypic.com/kew60n.jpg

Comment: Is this something you want? http://jsfiddle.net/hMEad/4/

Comment: Yes. Kind of. But i need the inputs to stay in place al the time, and not to show off after i selcet an option. Also, how di i display a "go button" as a result?

Comment: So this is what you had in mind? http://jsfiddle.net/hMEad/19/

Comment: Yes, and i saw the hyperlink. But i need it to be display after the third selected input (not the text type method).

Comment: Great! I change to a selected area and it is working! Thanks! Please write your comment as a solution so i can rank you!

Comment: Very good, yes, these inputs can be just about any type, i wanted to show the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to watch inputs with specific class all disabled. Check if they got value set up and eventually enable next input with same class within the same form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $forms = $('form');

    $forms.each(function(){

        var $form = $(this);

        // scan each form for inputs with .input-step class
        var $steps = $(this).find('.input-step');
        if ( $steps.length > 0 ) {
            $steps.not(':first').prop('disabled', true);
            $steps.change(function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                if ( val !== '' ) {
                    checkSubmitAvailability($form);
                    $form.find('.input-step:disabled:first').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});

// Checks if all steps were made
// eventually enables submit actions
function checkSubmitAvailability($form) {
    if ($form.find('.input-step:disabled').length === 0 ) {
        $form.find('.input-finish').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            if ( typeof $(this).attr('href') !== 'undefined' ) {
                // element has attribute href, add data to this attribute
                var data = $form.find('.input-step');
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?' + data.serialize());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Im using one form as scope and input with class "input-step" here, but that could be any other.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hMEad/19/

Answer (score 0):

I just add:

```
$('input').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/Mm2mu/4/